# TO_TIMESTAMP FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I HAVE A COLUMN NEW_DATE OF NUMBER(DATATYPE) AND I WANT TO GET A TIMESTAMP AND I TRIED THIS

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(NEW_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD-MON-YYYY'))
FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```

I GOT OUTPUT AS 18-01-21 12:00:00.000000000 AM AND I WANT IT TO BE 18-JAN-2021.

Answer (score 1):

`to_char` would return value in desired format:

```
SQL> with tw_edu_infra_amenities (new_date) as
  2    (select '2021-01-18' from dual)
  3  select to_char(to_date(new_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dd-MON-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') result
  4  from tw_edu_infra_amenities;

RESULT
-----------
18-JAN-2021

SQL>
```

If you applied `to_timestamp` to it, you *will* convert value into a timestamp, but - will you see it the way you wanted, depends on your client NLS settings. For example, in my database:

```
SQL> WITH tw_edu_infra_amenities (new_date) AS (SELECT '2021-01-18' FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (
  3            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (new_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  4                     'dd-MON-yyyy',
  5                     'nls_date_language = english'),
  6            'dd-MON-yyyy',
  7            'nls_date_language = english') result
  8    FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18.01.21 00:00:00,000000000

SQL>
```

That's how I see it; your (or someone else's) database *might* display it differently. If you want, you can alter session:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd-MON-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH tw_edu_infra_amenities (new_date) AS (SELECT '2021-01-18' FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (
  3            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (new_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  4                     'dd-MON-yyyy',
  5                     'nls_date_language = english'),
  6            'dd-MON-yyyy',
  7            'nls_date_language = english') result
  8    FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18-SIJ-2021

SQL>
```

Wait! What is that 18-**SIJ**-2021? That's Croatian *January* (we call it "Siječanj"). Hence all those `nls_date_language` parameters I used. If you don't want to use it, alter session once again:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH tw_edu_infra_amenities (new_date) AS (SELECT '2021-01-18' FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (
  3            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (new_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  4                     'dd-MON-yyyy',
  5                     'nls_date_language = english'),
  6            'dd-MON-yyyy',
  7            'nls_date_language = english') result
  8    FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18-JAN-2021

SQL>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

A `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data type consisting of 7-20 bytes (representing one byte for each of century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second then, optionally, up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds and 7 bytes for time zone information). It is **NEVER** stored in any particular human readable format.

If you want a `TIMESTAMP` data type then you will get the binary values and can use:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(NEW_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM   tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```

How that binary value is displayed to you, the user, depends on the client application you are using to connect to the database. Some client applications will have their own configuration and you can set how it displays all timestamps and could change that to `DD-MON-YYYY` (or the equivalent format model for the client application).

Oracle's SQL*Plus and SQL Developer client applications will use the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameters as the default for how they display timestamps and you can change those values in your session using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'English';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
```

That will affect all timestamps that you display in that client application.

---

If you want a formatted string then you do not want a `TIMESTAMP` returned and want a string instead and can use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP(NEW_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
         'DD-MON-YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       )
FROM   tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```